# Permanent environment variables for ubuntu (system, php, phpfpm and nginx or apache)

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, nginx, environment-variables

I am trying to set some system wide environment variables that will be accessible by any user on the system running ubuntu 14.04. I also need to set these same variables to be accessible by a php cli application, nginx & phpfpm web application and also an apache & phpfpm web application.

What would be the best way to go about setting them?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm an Ubuntu novice but recently I had to set the environment variables. I edited the file /etc/environment

I also have running nginx and php-cli, but I don't see what env variables they need to work. All their settings are contained in their conf files.

Comment: I have tried updating the /etc/environment and that works for the system, however does not pass through to php

Comment: @Pulkit: did you eventually find the solution to your problem?

Comment: Not quite. I started using laravel 5 which uses the `.env` file to pass environment variables to the application. So my current solution is to have the `/etc/environment` file for the system and the `.env` file for the application